# Can I use column index when using a converter in Pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in an excel file using Pandas.read_excel. I want to specify parameters I use in a date converter that is applied to columns x, y, z. The column names are unknown at the time of reading in the data but the column indexes are known.

example:

```
def parse_day_first(x):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(x, dayfirst=True)

pd.read_excel(filename, header=header, converters= {'Date': parse_day_first})
```

However in the converters dict the column name needs to be specified - which is not known as file may or may not have headers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel), the keys in the dictionary can be an integer or column label.

> converters : dict, default None Dict of functions for converting
>   values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column
>   labels, values are functions that take one input argument, the Excel
>   cell content, and return the transformed content.

If date is the first column in the excel file, let's try:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, header=header, converters= {0: parse_day_first})
```